# Simple string encounter

Tags: python, string

How would I take a string and only take up to a certain point in the string?
If I have the string:

```
testSetting = f"C:\Users\bgb\Documents\Brent\Code\Variable\Visual Studio\Local.testsettings"
```

The only part of the string I need is the `Local.testsettings` part, but I don't know how to accomplish this, I know you can use `string.strip()` But the part in the filepath that says `variable` changes every time the filepath gets triggered. (the filepaths are stored in a list and it's in a loop)

Comment: have you tried slices ?

Comment: I guess you meant `r"C:\..."`?

Comment: [os.path.basename](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) would probably help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There's a module for that](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html).

```
>>> import os.path
>>> testSetting = r"C:\Users\bgb\Documents\Brent\Code\Variable\Visual Studio\Local.testsettings"
>>> os.path.basename(testSetting)
'Local.testsettings'
```

There's also the complementary function:

```
>>> os.path.dirname(testSetting)
'C:\\Users\\bgb\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Variable\\Visual Studio'
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately

```
 testSetting.rpartition('\\')[2]
```

Comment: OK, but rather cryptic and not portable. What if his Python script should run on a Mac or Linux box one fine day? Suddenly the directory separator has changed. Oh no!

Comment: @TimPietzcker, agreed that `os.path` is the way to go in this specific instance. I'll leave this answer on as an example of the general-purpose value of rpartition